# C#: how to detect repeating values in an array and process them in such a way that each repeating value is only processed once?

Tags: c#, for-loop

I wrote this simple program:

```
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.Write("Number of elements in the array: ");
            int numberOfElements = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            int[] array = new int[numberOfElements];
            for(int i = 0; i < numberOfElements; i++)
            {
                Console.Write($"Element no {i+1}: ");
                array[i] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            }
            for(int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
            {
                int count = 0;
                for(int j = 0; j < array.Length; j++)
                {
                    if(array[i] == array[j])
                    {
                        count++;
                    }
                }
                Console.WriteLine($"{array[i]} appears " + count + " times");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is there any option to make the displayed values print only once?
For example, if there are three occurrences - the message displays three times. Is it possible to make it display once when there are more occurrences though?

Comment: There are various ways of doing this. For example, you could change the array type to `int?[]` and then when you find matching elements, set the array element to null - then skip those null elements. Or you could keep a set of "values you've already seen". Or you could make your inner loop check whether `j < i` when there's a match, in which case you should skip displaying the value as you'll already have displayed it.

Comment: I think what you are looking for is called "Histogram". Just in case you stumble across that word.

Comment: What is matching the last `}`? Left out?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The first idea I had was the same of the comment from Jon Skeet, since the simplicity it implies.

The idea is to set null for the value we have already counted (matched).

From a developer point of view it is very simple and doesn't deviate too much from the OP's code.

```
        Console.Write("Number of elements in the array: ");
        int numberOfElements = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        int?[] array = new int?[numberOfElements];
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfElements; i++)
        {
            Console.Write($"Element no {i + 1}: ");
            array[i] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
        {
            int count = 0;
            int? current = array[i];

            if (array[i] != null)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < array.Length; j++)
                {
                    if (current == array[j])
                    {
                        count++;
                        array[j] = null;
                    }
                }
                Console.WriteLine($"{current} appears " + count + " times");
            }
        }
```

`int?[]` defines a nullable value type. Therefore each item in the array can have either a null  or int value - documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/nullable-value-types).

Comment: That is what I need! Thanks so much! Both you and Jon :)
Can you please explain what these "?" after data type do?
I see it for the first time

Comment: @Sigma https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/nullable-value-types

Answer (score 12):

You could use a [`GroupBy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.groupby?view=netcore-3.1) instead of the *for loop*

> Groups the elements of a sequence.

```
var results = array
     .GroupBy(x => x)
     .Select(x => new {Value = x, Count = x.Count()});

foreach(var g in results)
   Console.WriteLine($"{g.Value} appears {g.Count} times");
```

---

Or another way it to use a [`HashSet`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1?view=netcore-3.1) to keep track of what you have displayed. A `HashSet` is basically a collection that contains no duplicate elements. The `Add` methods returns `true` if it can add an element or `false` otherwise

[`HashSet<T>.Add(T) Method`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1.add?view=netcore-3.1)

> returns true if the element is added to the HashSet object; false if the
> element is already present.

```
var hashSet = new HashSet<int>();
for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
{
    int count = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < array.Length; j++)
        if (array[i] == array[j])
            count++;

    // Add to the hashset, if the add method returns true, 
    // it means the value was uniquely added, ergo you have not displayed yet
    if (hashSet.Add(array[i]))
        Console.WriteLine($"{array[i]} appears " + count + " times");
}
```

[**Full Demo Here**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/8OvRMS)

---

Or another approach is to use a `Dictionary`. The premise is to iterate over the *array*, try an add each item to the dictionary with `TryAdd` if it's already found *increment* the value

```
var dictionary = new Dictionary<int,int>();
foreach(var item in array)
    if(!dictionary.TryAdd(item,1))
        dictionary[item]++;
    
foreach(var item in dictionary)
    Console.WriteLine($"{item.Key} appears {item.Value} times");
```

[**Full Demo Here**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/qIiUA9)

Comment: use HashSet instead of Dictionary

Answer (score 5):

An approach using `Dictionary` with `O(n)` complexity.

```
Console.Write("Number of elements in the array: ");

int numberOfElements = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
var dictionary = new Dictionary<int, int>();

for (int i = 0; i < numberOfElements; i++)
{
    Console.Write($"Element no {i + 1}: ");
    var value = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    if (!dictionary.ContainsKey(value)) dictionary.Add(value, 0);

    dictionary[value] = dictionary[value] + 1;
}

foreach (var item in dictionary)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{item.Key} appears {item.Value} times");
}
```

Comment: HashSet would be a better solution than Dictionary

Answer (score 4):

One simple way would be to swap your outer `for` loop with a `foreach` using a set to obtain distinct values.

So replace this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
```

With this:

```
foreach (int i in new HashSet<int>(array))
```

And this:

```
if (array[i] == array[j])
```

With this:

```
if (i == array[j])
```

Answer (score 3):

Other approach more suited for you would be too take only unique values from array, i.e.:

```
var unique = array.Distinct().ToArray();

for (int i = 0; i < unique.Length; i++)
{
    int count = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < array.Length; j++)
    {
        if (array[i] == array[j])
        {
            count++;
        }
    }
    Console.WriteLine($"{unique[i]} appears " + count + " times");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also use [Lookup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.lookup-2?view=netcore-3.1) here:

```
            var sb = new StringBuilder();
            foreach (var value in array.ToLookup(item => item))
            {
                sb.AppendLine($"{value.Key} appears " + value.Count() + " times");
            }
            
            Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
```

Answer (score 3):

In the inner loop, try to check if there were already any occurrences of the current element until you exceed the outer index.

```
for(int i = 0; i < array.Length-1; i++)
            {
                int count = 1;
                bool appeared = false;
                for(int j = 0; j < array.Length; j++)
                {
                    // until we are not at the same index as the outer loop
                    // check if we haven't already met the current element
                    if(j < i)
                    {
                        if (array[i] == array[j])
                        {
                            // set current value appearance to true
                            // to know if current element should be displayed
                            appeared = true;

                            // break the loop because there is no sense of continuing
                            // current look
                            break;
                        }   
                    }

                    // if we are ahead of outer index
                    // check if there are occurences of the element
                    else if(j > i)
                    {
                        if (array[i] == array[j])
                            count++;
                    }
                }

                // don't print the current element if it has appeared before
                if(!appeared)
                    Console.WriteLine($"{array[i]} appears {count} times");
            }
```

I believe there should be a more optimal solution, as this one's time complexity is linear... You can think of some optimization. For example, you can store occurred elements in the array and check through the array at each iteration, so you don't need to start the inner loop from the beginning, but instead start it from the outer loop's position + 1 but it's also not the best solution.

P.S check out about string interpolation, because you don't need to concatenate strings when you use it.